# Trying to encode an array to json in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I saw many threads on stackoverflow where people converted arrays into json.
And I am pretty sure that this should work, but it does not. MySQL is fine and the query is working as intended:

```
$json = array();
if($result = $mysqli->query($query)){
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
        $json[]["id"] = $row[0];
        $json[]["trivialname"] = $row[1];
        $json[]["chemischername"] = $row[2];
        $json[]["formel"] = $row[3];
    }
    echo $json[0]["id"]; //just for testing.
    echo json_encode($json);
}
```

Sorry for bad English.

My problem is mainly that echo json_encode($json); doesnt show anything

EDIT:
My Code look like this atm.

```
if($result = $mysqli->query($query)){
            $json = array();
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                $json[]=$row;
                printf("%s (%s) ID: %s, Formel:%s <br>", $row["Trvialname"], $row["Chemischername"], $row["ID"],$row["Formel"]);
            }
            echo json_encode($json);

        }
```

and it shows me this:

`Phthalimid (1,2-Benzoldicarboximid) ID: 2, Formel:C8H5NO2 
Phthalsäureanhydrid (2-Benzofuran-1,3-dion) ID: 3, Formel:C8H4O3`

nothing else!
i can change:

`echo json_encode($json);`

to

`echo json_encode($json[0]);`

and it will add the line :

`{"ID":"2","Trvialname":"Phthalimid","Chemischername":"1,2-Benzoldicarboximid","Formel":"C8H5NO2"}`

```
foreach($json[1] as $value){
    echo $value."<br>";
}
```

will show everything but

```
echo json_encode($json[1]);
```

doesnt.

**Solution**

```
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
```

**thanks to Your Common Sense**

Comment: Can you dump the array so we can see what it looks like?

Comment: what's wrong ? any error or what ?

Comment: You are adding a new item to $json array for each field in your while loop.  You should add them all at once when using `[]`

Comment: how about `var_dump($json)` at the end?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$json = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $json[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($json);
```

For the whole my life I'll never understand why PHP users always write so much code for the every trifle operation

You may also try json_last_error() and then add this call to your mysqli connect code

```
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
```

Comment: then your query doesn't return anything

Comment: it does i swear to god 
`echo $row[0]."<br>";
echo $row[1]."<br>";
echo $row[2]."<br>";
echo $row[3]."<br><br>";` returns everything i want

Comment: Then you are running not the code I posted but something else. Because the code I posted won't return $row[0]

Answer (score 2):

Update your code to

```
$json = array();
if($result = $mysqli->query($query)){
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
        $r = array();
        $r["id"] = $row[0];
        $r["trivialname"] = $row[1];
        $r["chemischername"] = $row[2];
        $r["formel"] = $row[3];
        $json[] = $r;
    }
    echo $json[0]["id"]; //just for testing.
    echo json_encode($json);
}
```

Comment: so `$result` is `false`. If your query return an empty array, at least you could see the string `[]` as an empty json array.

Answer (score 0):

You are not building your array the way you think you are.  Each element you are adding is adding a *new* row to the array, that's what `$json[]` does.  You will wind up with an array that looks like:

```
array(
    array('id' => 1),
    array('trivialname' => 'foo'),
    # etc.
)
```

What you want to do is:

```
$json[] = array(
    "id" => $row[0],
    "trivialname" => $row[1],
    "chemischername" => $row[2],
    "formel" => $row[3]
);
```

This will build the structure you desire.